# Passing object from AngularJS to ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm trying to pass some data to my MVC controller from AngularJS but the Customer object is always null on the MVC controller. What am I missing?

**Angular**

```
        $scope.new = {};

        $scope.AddCustomer = function () {
        $http.post('/Customer/SaveCustomer', $scope.new).success(function () {

        });
    }
```

**HTML**

```
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="CustomerID" ng-model="new.c.CustomerID" />
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="CompanyName" ng-model="new.c.CompanyName" />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="AddCustomer()">Save</button>
```

**C#**

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void SaveCustomer(Customer customer)
 {
     ....
 }

 public class Customer
 {
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Try new.CustomerID and new.CompanyName...

Comment: @ssilas777 thanks...That worked...I wonder why this tutorial I'm going through has it labeled as new.c.customerid

Comment: Ah, seems @ssilas777 beat me to it!

Comment: @Anonymous, Glad it worked, I have posted it as answer..Please mark as correct anwser if it helped.

Comment: use same naming convention on angular as your domain object.
    `customer.CustomerID` and do post `$scope.customer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your HTML like this :

Change `new.c.CustomerID` to `new.CustomerID`

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="CustomerID" ng-model="new.CustomerID" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="CompanyName" ng-model="new.CompanyName" />
```

Now this will work

```
$http.post('/Customer/SaveCustomer', $scope.new).success(function () {

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

First mind the camel case in javascript object

```js
$scope.new = {
  customerID: '',
  companyName: ''
}; 

$scope.AddCustomer = function() {
    $http.post('/Customer/SaveCustomer', $scope.new).success(function() {});
```

```html
<!--check the changes in ng-model-->
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="CustomerID" ng-model="new.customerID" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="CompanyName" ng-model="new.companyName" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="AddCustomer()">Save</button>



<!--Best of Luck-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model seems to be

```
new = {
  c : {
     CustomerID : '',
     CompanyName : ''
  }
}
```

Which doesn't map to your Customer class. You should refer to `new.CustomerID` and `new.CompanyName`. Futhermore I would avoid using the new keyword as variable name.