# Passing object from AngularJS to ASP.NET MVC Controller not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I am sending data from angularJS to MVC controller (I see that angularJS function **has argument value**, but on MVC controller side that **value is null**, and I have no clue why is that so...)

//function in angularJS controller

```
//initialize model
var model = {};
model.Name = "some string";
save(model, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
...

//post to MVC controller...
function save(model, success, error) {
    //name **has** value!
    return $http.post('/Test/Save', { params: { model: model } })
        .success(function (data) { errorHandler.jsonError(data, success, error); })
        .error(function (data, status) { errorHandler.httpError(data, status, error); });
}
```

//MVC controller side (TestController)

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save(SaveModel model) //SaveModel is a class that has Name property of type string
{
    //when debug reaches -> name is null...
    //...
}
```

And in that solution, there are other cases where data are saved seemingly same way and it works there... Any idea what to check, or what might be wrong? I'm new to angularjs, maybe I am missing something really simple...

P.S.

1) If I change "params:" to "data:" as suggested result is the same

2) If I remove "params:" then I get `500 error`. I.e. change:
`{ params: { model: model } }` -> `{ model: model }`

**PROBLEM/Solution**

So, the problem turned out to be **both** client and server side

1) on client side I had to change `{ params: { model: model } }` -> `model` as suggested by `StriplingWarrior`

2) on server side my `model` was inheriting from `BaseModel` which was setting some localization related stuff in it's constructor... and it was failing on my machine. The problem was that when debuging MVC controller -> this `BaseClass` code was performed before it, so it was hidden from me. I'm not yet common with browser `Developer Tools`, so I was not looking for information in the right place -> when I turned to `Network` tab (`Chrome Developer tools`), I could get exception information for my service call.

[Here is a similar case answered on SO. I seem to follow same rules without success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119662/passing-object-from-angularjs-to-asp-net-mvc-controller?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: try renaming `params:` to `data:`.  `params:` is for GET request

Comment: @S.Dav I I change `params:` to `data :` outcome is the same... on MVC controller side I receive name with null value. If I do as @StripplingWarrior suggested, then I get 500 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to [post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) is the actual data payload that you're posting, so you need to get rid of the `params` property and promote its object to the top level.

```
function save(name, success, error) {
    //name **has** value!
    return $http.post('/Test/Save', { name: name })
        .success(function (data) { errorHandler.jsonError(data, success, error); })
        .error(function (data, status) { errorHandler.httpError(data, status, error); });
}
```

### Update

Based on your updated code, you should be passing the model directly as the body of your request:

```
function save(model, success, error) {
    //name **has** value!
    return $http.post('/Test/Save', model)
        .success(function (data) { errorHandler.jsonError(data, success, error); })
        .error(function (data, status) { errorHandler.httpError(data, status, error); });
}
```

Comment: hmm, after I change it that way I get Internal server error 500

Comment: @Prokurors: Maybe try changing your input from a string to a model class that has a Name property on it. The `[FromBody]` attribute that Võ Quang Hòa recommended might also help.

Comment: I changed it to model with name property - now in controller I get this model, but name property is null

Comment: @StriplingWarrior .sucess and .error have been removed in the latest version of angularJs and will cause your app to crash. FYI.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - I found out why after using your recommended solution I got a `500 Internal server error`. There was a `BaseModel` class from which my model was inheriting, and this base model was having problems on my machine (related to localization) - when I fixed that issue, your solution did work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I am almost 100% sure you need to use `JSON.stringify()` method on your `name` object, as passing it directly just like that will not put your string in apostrophes, which is needed for MVC to treat this value as string object.

Please look at what exactly is sent by browser in `Developer tools'` Network card to confirm my theory.

Comment: Well, whoever downvoted my answer, maybe you should comment why?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is not needed, you can even send complex object without explicitly calling `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes, for complex objects it works, but I had such issue with Angular 5, that when I just put string, JS treated it like JSON string and didn't encapsulate in `" "`

Comment: I said "even complex object". And this is AngularJS, far from Angular 5

Comment: Yeah, I found plunker with AngularJS and tried it. Neither of versions put the data into `" "`.

The only way it worked, was to manually put it like: `'"' + testValue + '"'`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure it's work but you can try to change this

```
public JsonResult Save(string name)
```

To

```
public JsonResult Save([FromBody]string name)
```

When the param name is not null, you can check it's value and change from the angular part accordingly